# Oracle 8i Exists query

Tags: sql, exists, oracle8i

I am trying to speedup a query that is being run on a Oracle 8 server, against two tables that both have a few hundred thousands rows. The current query time varies from 12 to 30 seconds.

This is the original query:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT STOCK_ID
FROM
    STOCK_MOVES
WHERE
    ALTER_VAL IN (SELECT TO_CHAR(REZ) FROM REZ_TABLE WHERE NR_R = 1234)
AND
    DOCUMENT_CAT = 11
```

I tried to change it to the following and the query time dropped a few seconds:

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT STOCK_ID
FROM
   STOCK_MOVES, REZ_TABLE
WHERE
   ALTER_VAL = TO_CHAR(REZ) AND NR_R = 1234
AND
   DOCUMENT_CAT = 10
```

I am hoping that maybe if I try with EXISTS it will speed up but I don't know how to write the query. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Changing/upgrading the database engine is not an option at this time.

Comment: Because you are skipping the subquery

Comment: What do you mean?